# Getting an HTML element without id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, raphael

I have been working on drawing objects on a canvas with [raphael](/questions/tagged/raphael).
I want to pick up these objects on mouse click.

Earlier it was working with fetching the `target` object from the callback function like this:

```
VectorEditor.prototype.onMouseDown = function (x, y, target /*<--here*/, elem) {
```

However I had to implement other `div` overlays over this canvas. Because of this the above  `target` method no longer works.

Now I save the ids of the objects drawn in some data structure and need to get a handle when I click on the respective object (which is drawn on the canvas using Raphael).

I tried something like

```
elem.data("drawnID", shape.id); /*elem was the div (canvas) on which click was done*/
```

This gets overwritten once I draw multiple objects on the canvas. Clearly I need another mechanism to do this. Maybe using jagged arrays or such. In that case, how would I search the array to get a hold on the object clicked on the canvas since I don't have the id of the element clicked on the fly?